# Python: How to overlay 2 bar plots from pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to superimpose 2 bar plots with same x-xis.
I have a dataframe with this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,1,2,2,2],
             'b':[1,1,1,3,2,2,2]})
```

I can plot 2 histogram plots for a and b:

```
df['a'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
df['b'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]
[image]

How can i superimpose one of them on the other ?

Example of an unrelated chart format that im looking for:
[image]

Comment: As in a stacked bar plot?

Comment: Overlay where the back bar plot is more opaque than the front. Please see my updated example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `width` and `ax` paramters:

```
ax = df['a'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', color='blue', width=.75, legend=True, alpha=0.8)
df['b'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', color='maroon', width=.5, alpha=1, legend=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i think you are missing `value_counts()` like this: `ax = df['a'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', color='blue', width=.75, legend=True, alpha=0.8)`

Comment: Ah yes.  Feel free to edit solution.  I am away from computer at moment.   Thanks.