# Subplotting Pandas pivot_table into matplotlib figure creates a new figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create two bar graphs in one figure using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = read_csv(...)

temp1 = df['Credit_History'].value_counts(ascending=True)
temp2 = df.pivot_table(values='Loan_Status',index=['Credit_History'],aggfunc=lambda x: x.map({'Y':1,'N':0}).mean())

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
temp1.plot(kind='bar')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
temp2.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

The figure is set up correctly, the subplots are created, and temp1 is plotted, but when I try to plot temp2 (the pivot table) it creates a new figure on me instead of drawing onto the second subplot. This only seems to happen with the pivot_table. I'm able to plot temp1 twice onto both subplots, and even if I try to plot temp2 first it still creates a new figure.

Here's a screenshot of what's happening:

[image: Screenshot of Multiple Figures]
Instead of creating the pivot_table plot in the empty subplot in Figure 1, it creates a new Figure 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50011617/6361531 Does this SO post help?

Comment: @Parfait I've added a screenshot of my issue to the question, thanks.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks, but it's a bit of a different issue than the one you linked. I've added a screenshot to my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the issue derives because you are pairing a *pandas Series* (*temp1* from `value_counts` call) plot and a *pandas DataFrame* (*temp2* form `pivot_table` call) plot. Since your pivot table results in a one-column dataframe, consider [`squeeze()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) to downcast dataframe into a 1-dimensional series. And then from there plot as usual:

```
temp1 = df['Credit_History'].value_counts(ascending=True).sort_index()

temp2 = df.pivot_table(values='Loan_Status', index='Credit_History',
                       aggfunc=lambda x: x.map({'Y':1,'N':0}).mean())
temp2 = temp2.squeeze()
```

Below demonstrates with random data in the hope *df* replicates your original data structure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42518)   # SEED FOR RANDOM REPRODUCIBILITY
df = pd.DataFrame({'Credit_History': np.random.choice(['debt', 'credit'], 50),
                   'Loan_Status': np.random.choice(['Y', 'N'],50),
                   'Amount': abs(np.random.randn(50))*1000
                  }, columns = ['Credit_History','Loan_Status','Amount'])

temp1 = df['Credit_History'].value_counts(ascending=True).sort_index()

temp2 = df.pivot_table(values='Loan_Status', index='Credit_History',
                       aggfunc=lambda x: x.map({'Y':1,'N':0}).mean())
temp2 = temp2.squeeze()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
temp1.plot(kind = 'bar')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
temp2.plot(kind = 'bar')

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Output]